# Vibrate pattern in Chrome Notification does not apply

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, notifications, vibration

I am pushing notifications to Android devices (7.0 and 8.1) via Chrome and a serviceworker.
Within the service worker, I am creating the notifications like that:

```
const pattern = [500, 250, 500, 250, 500, 250, 500, 250, 500, 250, 500];

self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                    body: body,
                    icon: 'img/icon_256.png',
                    badge: 'img/icon_256.png',
                    vibrate: pattern,
                    tag: `ticket-${cartName}`,
                    renotify: ticketsToShow.length > 0,
                    actions: [{ action: 'overview', title: 'Übersicht öffnen' }],
                    data: { sessionId },
});
```

I **do** receive the notification and it vibrates, but no matter what number I put into the pattern const (or put it to vibrate directly), I'll always get the default vibrate pattern (2 very short vibrates after each other).

I also tried using the example provided [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/notifications/vibrate.html), but always with the same result ... just 2 very short vibrates)

Comment: When add a button to the website to call the vibrate function it does work fine: 
navigator.vibrate(1000);

Comment: I also tried to use https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-05/02-display-a-notification/#vibrate on my phone with same negative result

Comment: Could it possibly be an issue with your test device not supporting it? Maybe try using a different Android device and seeing if the problem persists. If I remember correctly, only newer devices can use custom patterns, even in native apps.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it is a problem with the Android Version. But it is actually the other way around, it used to work on older devices, but not on new ones.

Comment: @Stef I land on this one year later as your post and face the same behavior. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @DavidDalBusco Nope, I contacted the author via email (and his awesome guy actually replied!) and he told me that it is somehow deprecated on chrome for android. I haven't touched the topic ever since. Too bad actually.

Comment: @Stef thx for the feedback, I see then, agree with you too bad, that would have be a nice feature for my project

Comment: I have the same issue, but my phone doesnt vibrate at all. In microsoft edge the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @Stef I added an answer with a different approach to achieve this. Can you please give a try and check if it works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern is working fine with `window.navigator.vibrate` method but as you want to vibrate only when notification sent. Hence, For just a work around, can you give a try by invoke the vibration separately immediately after sending the notification ?

```
<notifications-loop>
  <notification>
  </notification>
  window.naviagtor.vibrate(500);
</notifications-loop>
```